# Label shape with multiple labels from one cell content

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

I have a Layer with different areas. Within the attribute table I have a column for measures to be taken. Within these cells there can be multiple measures.

| ID | Measures |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | M1, M2, M3 |
| 2 | M2, M3, M4 |

I would like to label the areas with these "Mx" labels separately, so every area would have three different labels in this example.

I can create different labels using Rulebased Labeling and offsetting them a bit so every one is visible. But when I move the labels for adjusted placement, all but one disappear.

Is there a better way to label areas with multiple labels?

Comment: What have you tried? Add screenshots of your rules to the question. What do you mean when you say "move the labels for adjusted placement"? I was able to get Rule Based Labelling to show 3 labels for each area so it's hard to tell what to change without you providing more information.